# How to call a function on refresh in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, function, meanjs

I have 2 functions in which 1 is called from the other

```
  callfunction1()
    $scope.function1 = function (data) {
        $('#sample-model').modal('show');
     };

 function callfunction1(){
    $scope.onClickSupport();
 }
```

I am triggering the first function through a button but when ever the page is refreshed function 1 should be called which is not happeng with my code.Here on debugging the console is not enterring the callfunction1().Can anyone help me please.Thanks.

Comment: Just say `$scope.callfunction1()` in your controller.

Comment: I am getting $scope.callfunction1() is not a function.

Comment: when i called it like you said

Comment: Can you create a plunkr so that it would be easy to solve the issue ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hmsPVU3WkiGNOSAsV8ca?p=preview

Comment: You haven't defined a module and controller in the plunkr. Replicate the exact code your getting this issue for in the plunkr including html.

Comment: How about calling your function after creating it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
 <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="yourFunctionwhichuwanttocall('%some_backend_value%')"></div>
```

because on page reload you can initialize your controller view with a function call . so in html

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="function1('%some_backend_value%')"></div>
```

After that call function 2.thanks hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

The ng-init directive initializes application data.

```
<div ng-init="function1()" ></div>

$scope.function1=function(){
     //your code
}
```